# Retornar registros que menos se repetem

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela 
`registro` com estrutura 
`'id(AI)', 'b1(INT 2)', 'b2(INT 2)', 'b3(INT 2)', 'b4(INT 2)', 'b5(INT 2)'` 
que recebe os valores inseridos no FORM da página inserir.php, 
exemplo como os dados são salvos:

`'ID=1','12','13','6','7','2'
'ID=2','6','7','1','7','15'`

na tabela `classes` com a estrutura `'id(AI)', 'nome(TEXT)'` já tem os dados pre inseridos como `'1,a','2,b','3,c'...'20,t'` respectivamente.

estou tentando contar quantas vezes os ID's a medida que são inseridos se repetem e sempre listar os 10 que se repetem menos.

Minha aplicação é PHP, a pagina index.php esta assim:

```
<?php session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$date = date('d-m-Y');
$datec = date('Y-m-d');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <title>estudo teste</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../adm/assets/libs/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../adm/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
<body>
<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM classes ORDER BY id ASC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, $query);
while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
$id = $linhas['id'];
$nome = $linhas['nome'];

$total = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE b1='$id' OR b2='$id' OR b3='$id' OR b4='$id' OR b5='$id'";
$resultado_total = mysqli_query($conectar, $total);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_total);

if($total != ''){
echo $nome." / ".$total."<br>   ";
}}

?>
 </body>
</html>
```

no momento só consigo contar quantas vezes ele se repete,
a intenção é retornar mais ou menos assim:

```
Resultado ID 12-i = 1
Resultado ID 01-a = 1
Resultado ID 07-g = 2 

...
```

Comment: editei com as informações que você pediu .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu exemplo não bate com a descrição do problema, mas deduzo que o resultado que você quer pode ser conseguido criando uma tabela auxiliar de números, a qual terá os valores possíveis:

```
CREATE TABLE numeros (
  numero VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO numeros(numero)
VALUES('01'), ('02'), ('03'), ('04'), ('05'),
      ('06'), ('07'), ('08'), ('09'), ('10'),
      ('11'), ('12'), ('13'), ('14'), ('15'),
      ('16'), ('17'), ('18'), ('19'), ('20');
```

Depois faça um `UNPIVOT` da sua tabela `registros` para gerar uma linha para cada coluna `b?`:

```
SELECT r.b1 AS numero FROM registros r
UNION ALL
SELECT r.b2 AS numero FROM registros r
UNION ALL
SELECT r.b3 AS numero FROM registros r
UNION ALL
SELECT r.b4 AS numero FROM registros r
UNION ALL
SELECT r.b5 AS numero FROM registros r
```

Após isso faça um `INNER JOIN` com a tabela auxiliar `numeros` que você criou previamente, utilizando a função de agregação `COUNT` para contar a quantidade de registros para cada número e um `ORDER BY` por essa quantidade. Em seguida utilize a cláusula `LIMIT` para limitar a 10 registros (que é o que você havia especificado na pergunta):

```
SELECT x.numero,
       COUNT(1) AS quantidade
  FROM (SELECT r.b1 AS numero FROM registros r
        UNION ALL
        SELECT r.b2 AS numero FROM registros r
        UNION ALL
        SELECT r.b3 AS numero FROM registros r
        UNION ALL
        SELECT r.b4 AS numero FROM registros r
        UNION ALL
        SELECT r.b5 AS numero FROM registros r) x
      INNER JOIN numeros n ON n.numero = x.numero
 GROUP BY x.numero
 ORDER BY 2, x.numero
 LIMIT 10
```

O resultado pode ser conferido no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/347ad8/9).

Aplicando o exemplo ao seu código teremos algo similar ao seguinte:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include_once("conexao.php");
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  $date  = date('d-m-Y');
  $datec = date('Y-m-d');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <title>estudo teste</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../adm/assets/libs/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../adm/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
<body>
<?php
  $query = "SELECT x.numero,\n";
  $query.= "       COUNT(1) AS quantidade\n";
  $query.= "  FROM (SELECT r.b1 AS numero FROM registros r\n";
  $query.= "        UNION ALL\n";
  $query.= "        SELECT r.b2 AS numero FROM registros r\n";
  $query.= "        UNION ALL\n";
  $query.= "        SELECT r.b3 AS numero FROM registros r\n";
  $query.= "        UNION ALL\n";
  $query.= "        SELECT r.b4 AS numero FROM registros r\n";
  $query.= "        UNION ALL\n";
  $query.= "        SELECT r.b5 AS numero FROM registros r) x\n";
  $query.= "      INNER JOIN numeros n ON n.numero = x.numero\n";
  $query.= " GROUP BY x.numero\n";
  $query.= " ORDER BY 2, x.numero\n";
  $query.= " LIMIT 10";

  $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, $query);

  while ($linhas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $numero     = $linhas['numero'];
    $quantidade = $linhas['quantidade'];

    echo $numero . " / " . $quantidade . "<br>   ";
  }
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: é exatamente isso, a sua tabela "numeros" é a minha tabela "classes", mas não to conseguindo fazer esse SELECT rodar na pagina php.

Comment: vou editar a perguntar, tentar deixar exatamente como o projeto esta

Comment: acredito que agora esteja mais claro

Comment: como não? se eu conseguisse chamar o SELECT da sua resposta, meu problema estaria resolvido, você respondeu com perfeição.